# Live broadcast software?

Tags: windows-xp, video, software-rec, live-broadcast

I'm looking for some software for a high school TV news broadcast. All the hardware is in place, with cameras interfacing with a computer (running XP) and the broadcast output being fed to a second screen. I just need some software to put it all together. Currently, we're using Adobe Visual Communicator 3, but this software requires you to use a pre-configured timeline. If anyone slips up and talks for too long (this is quite likely), then the software cuts to the next scene, no questions asked. I need something that's cue-based and has greenscreen capabilites.

What alternatives do I have?

Comment: Are you wanting to switch between live broadcasts and recorded content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Wirecast (*[Official Site](http://www.telestream.net/wire-cast/features.htm)*)

> Wirecast software lets you produce professional-looking live events with just a camera, an internet connection and a computer. Stream or record live internet shows, broadcast breaking news or sporting events, stream live concerts, transmit church services, corporate meetings, lectures and much more.
>
> With the intuitive interface and fully integrated streaming capabilities Wirecast makes it easy for anyone to share live experiences and build a global community. Wirecast **lets you stream multiple live video cameras while dynamically mixing in other media** such as movie clips, images, audio and text. Features such as Chroma Key (green screen), 3D transitions, built-in titles and up to 35 layers of live compositing allow you to create professional broadcast productions for live or on-demand distribution to services such as Ustream, Livestream and Justin.TV, as well as to a wide range of streaming servers. Wirecast Pro adds scoreboards, advanced audio control, 3D virtual sets and more.

Comment: The question is so unclear that it's not apparent that the questioner is actually after dynamic mixing, but I'm guessing that this fits.

Answer (score 0):

I found a wonderful article detailing [how to splice together content for uStream on the fly](http://www.conversationmarketing.com/2007/09/streaming_video_creating_a_pro.htm).

It recommends a $30 shareware called [WebcamMax](http://www.webcammax.com/index.php) which claims to splice together content on the fly with images and videos and can output it as a fake webcam so that you can uStream it.